# Как сделать так, чтобы все могли пользоваться моей базой данных PostgresQL

Tags: postgresql, spring, docker, docker-compose

Я начинающий программист, пишу веб-проект в команде с друзьями.
В разработке используем Spring Data, PostgresQL для бд. Я написал базовые сущности(@Entity) и создал таблицу для них в бд, однако я понимаю, что скорее всего, так как подключения идет таким образом:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ScheduleOfEvents_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
```

моим друзьям придется создавать самим таблицы в БД или же можно как-то сделать так, чтобы jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/ScheduleOfEvents_db - был удаленным ?
Мне сказали, что может помочь docker-compose, но я не совсем понимаю как это сделать
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблемы с удаленным БД